# (По)щипай или (по)щипли?

Tags: глаголы

Запуталась в повелительном наклонении глагола "щипать" (пощипать). В интернете много информации, но повелительное найти сложно. Нашла вариант "щипли". А разве "щипай" ("пощипай") нельзя?

Comment: По  моему  можно.

Answer (score 5):

Ну почему это "сложно найти"?

[Орфоэпический словарь Аванесова онлайн | dazor.narod.ru](http://dazor.narod.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0646.htm)

Словарь, конечно, не новый, но в нем как минимум представлены оба варианта. 
"Щипли" - как нормативный, "щипай" - как не рекомендуемый, по крайней мере - на тот момент.
Думаю, что так оно и сейчас есть.

Тут вот какая штука. "Щипать" в современном языке испытывает колебания в выборе набора форм: щипать-щиплет-щипли и щипать-щипет(и даже щипает)-щипай. 
Первый ряд - исторический, второй - более современный, пока еще не ставший бесспорно нормативным.
Так что лучше все-таки ***щипли***.
***Щипай*** - максимум как разговорный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется правильно два варианта- щипай и щипли.